# Move column b and column c to bottom of column a

Tags: python-2.7

Using pandas, I need to move column b and column c to the bottom of column a, such that the order from top to bottom is column a content over column b content over column c content.

```
cola colb colc 
a    c    b 
b    c    e 
e    f    d
```

want it to be

```
cola 
a 
b 
e 
c 
c 
f 
b 
e 
d
```

Comment: It looks like you're talking about a specific example. Could you please provide a labelled example of what this table should look like before and after your operation? Currently it is hard to interpret.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Hopefully this is readable.  I'm a nube and having trouble making codeblocks.  Currently it is...

    cola   colb   colc
    a           c        b
    b           c        e
    e           f        d

want it to be

    cola
    a
    b
    e
    c
    c
    f
    b
    e
    d

Comment: Comments cannot include newlines, so please edit your question to include your table. Once you've made the table, you can select it and use <Ctrl-K> (I think it's <Command-K> on mac) to format that as a code block.

Comment: thank you @ZoeyHewll i added codeblocks to the initial question...i was trying to do it in comments before. Nubes huh? thanks for the tip. hopefully my question makes sense now